# How to save info in asp.net core startup to be available in app

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a set of 7 .Net Framework WebApi-based services that all share some common design elements. One shared element is that each will include the service version in the data that it returns from any of its endpoints. In each service, I determine the version from the executing assembly using reflection. I do this in Application_Start and store the result in a property that I create on the Global class that inherits from System.Web.HttpApplication. That way I do the reflection work once and access the result later from each of my methods.

I'm building a new service and this one is built on ASP.NET Core. So I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing in ASP.NET Core. I can add the reflection logic in Startup.Configure (though it's not really about configuring the Http pipeline which is what Configure is supposed to be doing). Is there a better place than Startup.ConfigureServices or Startup.Configure, to put code that you want to run once on startup?

And where would I store the result to make it readily accessible to each of the downstream methods called from my controller actions?